# "Действительно" - нужны ли запятые?

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

Нужно ли слово "действительно" в тексте выделять запятыми?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Если "действительно" является в предложении вводным словом (и обозначает уверенность говорящего в информации), то оно выделяется запятыми. А в устной речи – паузами. Часто это слово стоит в начале предложения. К тому же, вводное слово можно переставить в другое место предложения, не нарушая его структуру.
Пример: *"Действительно, он очень красив" = "Он, действительно, очень красив"*.
Если же "действительно" – наречие, то запятыми оно не выделяется. Его невозможно переставить в другое место предложения без потери смысла, а кроме того, в речи на него обычно делается акцент.
Пример: *"Но я действительно хочу есть!"*

Answer (score 4):

Вводное слово *действительно* служит для подтверждения ранее высказанного утверждения, наречие *действительно* — для акцентирования ранее не высказанного утверждения.

Ср.: *Действительно, сложная музыка* (ранее уже утверждалось, что музыка сложная; в данном случае утверждается справедливость этого утверждения). — *Действительно сложная музыка* (цель сообщения — поделиться наблюдениями).

Говорящий может подтвердить высказанное утверждение, утверждая уже озвученную мысль заново (*«Его музыка очень сложна». — «Музыка действительно сложная, и в этом, на мой взгляд, ее великолепие»*), но вводное слово *действительно* выделению ранее не высказанных утверждений послужить не может.

Такие выводы я сделала по зрелом размышлении над разъяснениями вроде [этого](http://www.gramota.ru/spravka/punctum/58_166). Поправьте, если не права.

Answer (score 2):

1)  Действительно – это наречие со значением  «то, что соответствует действительности».  Как и всякое наречие, оно может относиться  к глаголу или к прилагательному:  действительно новый, действительно так,  действительно гарантировать. Именно в такой необособленной форме мы встречаем это наречие в большинстве случаев.

2) При обособлении наречие выполняет функцию вводного слова, относится ко всему предложению и является  оценкой всего сообщения.

3)  Рассмотрим пример:  Мне говорили, что город красив. Город действИтельно красИв.  Или: ДействИтельно, гОрод красИв.

Семантика здесь практически одинаковая, а структура и интонация предложений разные. В первом случае ударение падает на наречие, которое является структурным элементом предложения, во втором предложении вводное слово в его состав не входит.

4) Рассмотренный вариант является парным, но встречаются случаи, когда наречие  (обычно в начале предложения) обособляется обязательно, так как не может встроиться в структуру предложения в качестве акцентированного слова, например: Действительно, время свободное есть. Действительно, удержаться в запланированных рамках инфляции будет довольно сложно

5) Из всего этого делаем вывод, что окончательное решение об обособлении наречия «действительно» в качестве вводного слова делается не по семантике, а по структуре предложения.

ПРИМЕРЫ

1)  Не обособляется:

Он действительно оказался интересным и простым в общении собеседником. Смотрю ― в дневнике действительно ничего не написано. 
Это действительно новый этап в строительстве наших межгосударственных связей.

2) Обособляется:

Действительно, высокоточное дальнобойное оружие ― крайне опасное средство.
Действительно, никаких проблем с регистрацией не было. 
Действительно, деньгами можно распоряжаться по-разному.