# Нужно ли выделять запятыми "действительно" в этом предложении?

Tags: пунктуация, вводные-слова, запятые

*Если контракты краткосрочные и они истекают в ближайшее время, то это, действительно, может вызвать достаточно серьезные проблемы.* Нужно ли выделять запятыми "действительно" в этом предложении? Если да/нет, то почему? (Под словом "это" подразумевается тот факт, что компания Oracle разрывает контракты с нефтяными компаниями РФ.)

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: ["Действительно" - нужны ли запятые?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/91/%d0%94%d0%b5%d0%b9%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%82%d0%b5%d0%bb%d1%8c%d0%bd%d0%be-%d0%bd%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%bd%d1%8b-%d0%bb%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d1%8f%d1%82%d1%8b%d0%b5)

Comment: На этот вопрос нужно отвечать применительно к заданному предложению.

Comment: Слово "это" не может подразумевать тот факт, что компания Oracle... Это вам не это.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) **Наречие со значением соответствия действительности:**

Если контракты краткосрочные и они истекают в ближайшее время, то это **действительно** может вызвать достаточно серьезные проблемы.

2) **Сравнить (вводное слово со значением подтверждения того, что было сказано ранее, или с доказательством выдвинутого тезиса):**

**Действительно,** если контракты краткосрочные и они истекают в ближайшее время, то это  может вызвать достаточно серьезные проблемы.

В этом случае ***действительно*** стоит в начале предложения.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ!

Answer (score 4):

Различать **наречие** и **вводное слово** ***«действительно»*** очень непросто. **Вводное слово** отличается интонационной обособленностью (при устном прочтении оно выделяется интонационной паузой) и оттенком значения: вводное слово «действительно» выражает уверенность говорящего в истинности сообщаемого факта;
 **наречие** «действительно», как правило, **притягивает на себя фразовое ударение** (Ср.: *Ты очень устал – Ты действительно очень устал*); по своему значению оно синонимично прилагательному «действительный» – «настоящий, подлинный». В спорных случаях вопрос о расстановке знаков препинания решает автор текста. [Действительно](https://punktuaciya.academic.ru/201/%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE)

***Если контракты краткосрочные и они истекают в ближайшее время, то это действительно может вызвать достаточно серьезные проблемы.*** *(Наречие ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО притягивает фразовое ударение, но не выделяется паузами.)*