# Запятые при слове "действительно"

Tags: пунктуация, запятые, вводные-слова

В каком из предложений нужно выделять слово "действительно" запятыми?

1. И это действительно так.
2. Любовь действительно не подвластна никаким законам.

Comment: А ответ "ни в каком" принимается?

Answer (score 3):

1. **И это действительно так.**
   В этом предложении "действительно" употреблено в значении "на самом деле" (запятыми в этом случае не выделяется).

*Пропаганда вторична. И это действительно так.

«Студенческие отряды — это путешествие». И это действительно так!*

2. **Любовь действительно не подвластна никаким законам.**
   И в этом предложении я бы (как автор) тоже обошлась без запятых.
   Без контекста довольно трудно определить, является ли слово "действительно" вводным.

Сравните:  *Да, действительно, любовь не подвластна времени!*
Здесь и структура предложения другая, и смысл другой — обособление необходимо.

[ДЕЙСТВИТЕЛЬНО, вводное слово](http://old-punctum.ru/punctum.php?sid=166)

Answer (score 2):

В обоих случаях слово ***действительно***  не выделяется запятыми.

Эта тема уже рассматривалась на форуме: ["Действительно" - нужны ли запятые?](https://rus.stackexchange.com/questions/91/%D0%94%D0%B5%D0%B9%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%BD%D1%8B-%D0%BB%D0%B8-%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%8F%D1%82%D1%8B%D0%B5)

Слово ***действительно*** чаще бывает наречием, а в качестве вводного слова употребляется **в двух случаях** (причем обычно  с вводного слова начинается предложение):

1) начало доказательства какого-либо утверждения;

2) вывод в конце доказательства; вывод, подтверждающий ранее высказанную мысль; вывод о соответствии  факта действительности.

(1) Действительно, любовь законам не подвластна (начало доказательства). Об этом говорили многие поэты, и это мы видим на реальных жизненных примерах...

(2) Да, действительно, у любви нет законов (вывод в конце доказательства).